# VBA: Match-function with two workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I want to see if the value in column A of one workbook is in column A of another workbook (and then return the row). However, I'm stuck at using match.

I tried different approaches with the match function, first with a reference, then I simply typed in a number to match. The problem is: As long as the current workbook (`wbCurr`) is open, it always looks for the value there. When I close it, it looks in the master file (`wbMaster`) which is what I want.

```
Sub ReportCreation()
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wbCurr As Workbook As Workbook
    Dim pathMaster As String, pathCurrent As String As String
    Dim rowMaster As Variant
    Dim rowCurrent As Long, lRowCurrent As Long, lRowMaster As Long



    pathMaster = "C:\Users\VBA\report2019.xlsx"
    pathCurrent = "C:\Users\VBA\report 042019.xlsx"


    Set wbMaster = Workbooks.Open(pathMaster)
    Set wbCurr = Workbooks.Open(pathCurrent) 'current month


'    rowMaster = Application.Match(wbCurr.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 1), wbMaster.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0)
    rowMaster = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(7, wbMaster.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0)
    Debug.Print rowMaster

End Sub
```

Comment: Your commented-out line should work fine - Match will only search the range passed in to the second argument

Comment: @Tim Williams It didn't. Now I'm on a different computer and it does work...any idea why?

Comment: NoNameNo123 could I interest you in using dictionaries? You store one of the two workbooks Column A values along with their rows. And then loop through the other workbook just asking the dictionary if each item exists in it, then print the row belonging to it.

Comment: What is `wbCurrent`?

Comment: @SJR fixed,it's `wbCurr`. Doesn't change anything about the problem I had on the other PC though.

Comment: @Damian What's the advantage? Is this faster or less error prone?

Comment: @NoNameNo123 both, only thing is that they are case sensitive. If that is not a problem, your macro will run in a  matter of seconds and with 100% accuracy.

Comment: @Damian I'm dealing with contract numbers, so that's not an issue. I'll look into it, thank you!